# Logical exception vs technical exception

Tags: java, exception

There is a restriction on the database level in the user table for the unique field - email. That is, if we try to save the user with an existing email address, then an SQLServerException will occur. In this case, we can catch this technical exception, create and then throw our own **technical exception**.

But we can also make a request to the database and check if the user exists and then throw our own a **logical exception**.

The question is which of the options is more preferable?

Comment: Technical and Logical exceptions are not java types, that question does not make much sense to me I am afraid. But I'd say that is it normal that you throw an exception when you try to insert an email that already exists. For the other case (querying to see if the user already exists), I'd rather have a method that return a boolean rather than an exception

Comment: Technical and logical exceptions are another classification of exceptions. What is a logical exception? - For example, the user inputs incorrect values, and as a result, we get a negative balance value. According our logic, the balance cannot be negative, then we should throw an exception to it.

Comment: @Bentaye logical exceptions are also called business exceptions

Comment: @Nico I would be interested to know your opinion about the case(check if a user exists using db query) this exception is business?

Comment: @alexis_druzik yes it's a business exception, you decide your software doesn't allow a user to be registered twice. But you you could choose to allow a user to be registered several times (but of course it doesn't make sense for a user experience to have several accounts with same email... and also it doesn't make for other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

It depend on your requirement

1. In case of 1 option you need to had to have constrains on email field. Then while catching the exception you need to be careful that thats indeed constrains violation on email field. Only advantage i can see here that you have to do only one query to db.
2. In 2nd case you have all the control, you can explicitly check if email already exist in separate db query and if not throw exception, otherwise make additional query to insert the data.
   Here you have to make 2 db call, but you have better control over behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to check the database and not use the constraint of your database.

The database constraints must be seen as a second shield to ensure data integrity. But it musn't drive your business logic. Only your software drives your business logic.